# Using a loop to create variables named after elements in a list

Tags: python, list, variables, tkinter, iteration

I'm trying to create a sign-up form using Python and Tkinter...

To keep things tidy, I would like to iterate over the elements of this **`list`**:

```
signup_fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'password', 'confirm_password', 'email', 'confirm_email', 'height', 'weight']
```

With something like this **`for`** loop being used to create the entry boxes:

```
for field in signup_fields:
    {field} = tk.Entry()
    {field}.pack()
```

As you can see, I'm putting 'field' in '{}' curly brackets to try get Python to name the variables based on the strings from the list. I don't know how to do this and I'm not finding a workaround online.

Comment: I just want to emphasize what Bryan said in his answer: **you don't want to do that**.    It is possible through trickery to create variable-named variables, but it's always a bad idea.  It's not the right way to do things.  Use a list or a dict.

Comment: It is technically possible to do this with exec or globals/locals but I will third the advice to use a dict. Every other way is worse. Use a dict.

Comment: @CJR technically, it is *not* possible in local scopes, only global scopes

Comment: Do *not* do this. Use a *container*, like a list or a dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to do that. Instead, store the widgets in a dictionary. The code will be much easier to understand and debug.

```
entries = {}
for field in signup_fields:
    entries[field] = tk.Entry()
```

For other alternatives, see [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)